# Residual vs fitted plot analysis

Tags: r, regression, lm

That is the original diagonostic plot
[image]

This is after the log transformation, still looks like all the observations are scattered on the right hand side. 
[image]

Comment: The distribution left-to-right will simply be the distribution of your x variable. In this case you've confused the interpretation somewhat by using splines on the RHS of your formula.

Comment: I edited the question, even without the splines, the observations are still on the RHS. I don't think spline is the problem? My response variable is infant birth weight, is it normal that value is greater than 0, like 7?